# Hexagon Consisting of Complex Numbers

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, vectors

In the Argand plane, the points Q and A represent the complex numbers 4+6i and 10+2i respectively. If A, B, C, D, E, F are the vertices, taken in clockwise order, of a regular hexagon with centre Q, find the complex number which represents B. How do I find the coordinate of B?

Comment: Hint: Draw a circle with the same radius, all the vertices will lie on it

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: Sketch of a solution: You should know a way to rotate a point a specified amount around $0$.  Translate all the points so that $Q$ moves to $0$, rotate the appropriate amount, and then translate again so that $0$ moves back to $Q$.  If for some reason you don't know how to do some of these steps, you need to specify more information in the question so that we could reasonably guess what you do or don't know.

Comment: $Q$, $A$, and $B$ form an equilateral triangle. Given the locations of $Q$ and $A$, that leaves two possibilities for $B$, and the "clockwise" restriction leaves only one. So, it's geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given one *spoke* of a hexagon (i.e., the radial lines from the center to the vertices). The next point on the hexagon is just a rotation of that spoke by $\pi/3$ ($60^{\circ}$). Hence,

$$
B=(A-Q)e^{i\pi/3}+Q
$$

Alternatively, you can consider the hexagon on a unit circle, say,

$$
z=e^{ik\pi/3},\quad k\in[0,5]
$$

and the find the points you want by RST (rotation, scaling, translation)

$$
R=\arg(A-Q)\\
S=|A-Q|\\
T=Q\\
Z=zSe^{iR}+Q
$$